# Filtro por fechas no muestra datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una tabla con registros de facturas, estoy filtrando por fecha pero no me muestra nada

```
    <form method="POST">        

        <div id="fechas">
        <label id="lbfecha" for="">Fecha Inicial</label><!--Fecha Inicial-->
        <input id="ipfecha" type="date" name="fecha1" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"><!--Fecha Inicial-->
        <label id="lbfecha" for="">Fecha Final</label><!--Fecha Final-->
        <input id="ipfecha" type="date"  name="fecha2" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"><!--Fecha Final-->
        <input type="submit" name="Filtrar" value="Filtrar">
        </div>


<!--=====================================
=            TABLA                =
======================================-->
    <div id="tablapedidodet"> <!--estilo de la tabla css/pedidodet.css-->   
        <br/>
        <table align="center"> <!-- inicia tabla-->
            <thead>
                <tr> <!-- inicia encabezado de la tabla-->
                    <!--<th>checkbox</th>  columnas de la tabla-->
                    <th>id</th> <!-- columnas de la tabla-->
                    <th>XML</th> <!-- columnas de la tabla-->
                    <th>PDF</th> <!-- columnas de la tabla-->
                    <th>FECHA</th> <!-- columnas de la tabla-->
                    <th>UDN</th> <!-- columnas de la tabla-->
                </tr> <!-- termina encabezado de la tabla-->
            </thead>

    <?php 

            $f1=isset($_POST['$fecha1']);
            $f2=isset($_POST['$fecha2']);

            $sqlfechas = "SELECT
                                fac_codigo_k,
                                fac_xml,
                                fac_pdf,
                                DATE_FORMAT(fac_fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') AS fac_fecha,
                                sysudn_codigo_k
                            FROM
                                facturas
                            WHERE
                                fac_fecha 
                            BETWEEN 
                                STR_TO_DATE('$f1','%d/%m/%Y') 
                            AND 
                                STR_TO_DATE('$f2','%d/%m/%Y')";
            if (isset($_POST['Filtrar'])) {
            $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sqlfechas);
            while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { //muestra resultados
    ?> 
            <tr>
                <td><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><?php echo $mostrar['fac_codigo_k']?></td> <!-- muestra codigo de registro-->
                <td><a href="<?php echo $mostrar["fac_xml"];?>" download="<?php echo $mostrar["fac_xml"];?>"><?php echo $mostrar['fac_xml']?></a></td> 
                <td><a href="<?php echo $mostrar["fac_pdf"];?>" download="<?php echo $mostrar["fac_pdf"];?>"><?php echo $mostrar['fac_pdf']?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['fac_fecha']?></td> <!-- muestra registro de pdf-->
                <td><?php echo $mostrar['sysudn_codigo_k']?></td> <!-- muestra udn-->
            </tr>

            <?php
                }} //termina de mostrar resultado 
            ?>

            </thead>
        </table> <!-- termina tabla-->
    </div>
<!--====  End of TABLA  ====-->
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Probaste la consulta en phpMyAdmin para verificar que realmente devuelve resultados?
¿Que hay de **$_POST['Filtrar']**? ¿Se envia algun valor por Post? Tal vez no entra por esa condición.
Si verificaste todo eso, prueba en la query modificar:

```
WHERE fac_fecha
```

por

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(fac_fecha, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Saludos

Comment: si de echo fue lo primero que hice antes te armar el código

saludos!

Comment: en $_POST['Filtrar'] cuando se precione el boton Filtrar se mostraran los resultados

Comment: ¿Filtrar lo estas enviando desde un formulario?
<form method="post" target="filtrado.php">

Comment: si tengo el metodo post pero lo estoy haciendo directamente desde index.php

Comment: prueba añadiendo las lineas

echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

a ver que resultados te muestra

Comment: me muestra esto:
Array ( [fecha1] => 2018-10-02 [fecha2] => 2018-10-02 [Filtrar] => Filtrar )

Comment: Esto es lo que ingreso en mis campos tipo Date :
Fecha Inicial  
01/07/2018
 Fecha Final  
03/08/2018 
y como resultado me da esto: 
Array ( [fecha1] => 2018-07-01 [fecha2] => 2018-08-03 [Filtrar] => Filtrar )
me imagino que es en el momento en que formatea la fecha al formato indicado para la consulta

Comment: Estas pasando las fechas como YYY-MM-DD y en tu código lo estas tomando como DD/MM/YYYY.
Debes modificar la query para que lo tome de ese modo, o sea:
**STR_TO_DATE('$f1','%Y-%m-%d')** y lo mismo para $f2

Comment: ya lo modifique pero al momento de cambiar las fechas igual no se cambian los datos de la tabla, me muestra todos los datos como si hiciera un select * from

Comment: en la consulta en la parte del where igual como me comento que le cambiara a *DATE_FORMAT(fac_fecha, '%d/%m/%Y')* pero si lo cambio por _fac_fecha_ se quita todo ya no me muestra nada